# In OPA why does multiple calls to Network.cloud("key") from different pages return different clouds?

Tags: opa

I evaluate OPA to create a realtime collaborative spreadsheet (source here :
https://github.com/omarbenhamid/Cloudsheet/blob/master/cloudsheet.opa)

I want people to calloborate in realtime on spreadsheets, I want to create a Network.cloud for each spreadsheet to communicate updates to all users viewing the spreadsheet.

Each cell is an `<input type="text" onkeypress={event->keyboard_update(event,sheetname,row,column)}/>`

When `keyboard_update` is called i want to broadcast a message on spreadsheet's clouds so that other viewers get updated. But here is my problem :

```
keyboard_update(event,sheetname,row,column) = (
    Network.broadcast({/*my update notif message*/}, Network.cloud(sheetname))
)
```

This behaves just like a new network is created at each call even thow API doc of Network.cloud says :

> "When one or several servers invoke Network.cloud(k) with the same value k, only one network is actually created"

The only solution I found is to index my clouds in an associative list that is stored in a global mutable :

```
clouds = Mutable.make([] : list((string,Network.network(message))))
```

And fetch my cloud using List.assoc and eventually add it to the index if necessary (see function getcloud in the source code).

Why does my first approach of using Network.cloud(sheetname) as parameter of Network.broadcast misbehave ?

Comment: But if you really want to create multple clouds, you should at least use a stringmap(Network.network(message)), which will give use instant access to a particular cloud

Comment: I did not use map because I read in API doc that string map is immutable : `an immutable data structure`. Did i misunderstand ?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between using a StringMap or List as a Mutable.

Comment: I think `immutable data structure` means you can't update it just with StringMap.add for exemple

Comment: Thanks, for explanation I will try to turn it into StringMap so it will be certainly more straightforward.

Comment: I believe there was a problem with the implementation of Network.cloud that is being addressed now by our (MLstate's) team. Stay tuned for more info...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should create a new Cloud for each cell.
You should just create one cloud for the entire document, or maybe webapp, and have diferent type of message sent :

For example :

```
type cloud_message = {
  sheet_name : string
  row : int
  col : int
  content : string
}
```

And then, only create the cloud once, at top-level :

```
@publish my_cloud = Network.cloud("my_cloud") : Network.network(cloud_message)
```

And finally, in your keyboard_update, call :

```
Network.broadcast({sheet_name=... row=... col=... content=...}, my_cloud)
```

Comment: Indeed, I don't have one cloud per cell, it is one cloud per document but I have multiple documents thus I need multiple clouds

Comment: Yes, i thought Network.cloud was creating a new cloud at each call. my bad.